# How to sort prompt values in a Webi report?

Tags: sorting, business-objects, webi

I have prompt for Fiscal Month in my Webi Report. I want to custom sort it so that the month starts with April, May, June , etc.

How is this possible?

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many ways like adding LOVs and managing to sort the values at prompt, etc. But in BO 4.1, How we should do is,

1.Click on Parameters and List of Values.

2. In Edit SQL write the query with order by so that we get the order. for eg. select distinct fiscal_month,fiscal_month_number from calender_table order by fiscal_month_number.
3. Validate the query.
4. In Properties tab, check for hiding fiscal_month_number and give a appropriate name for fiscal_month column.
5. Now in Business Layer, select the dimension we created for fiscal_month, in Advanced Tab, add the List of Value that is created.

Thanks

Niki